# Assign B2C Users to Azure Storage Containers for API System

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-ad-b2c

The API my company is creating is made to interact with an Azure Storage account. The user logs in using a SPA hosted by the Azure Storage account with B2C. The user then interacts with an Azure Function that creates a request from the B2C user's input information, and then sends the blob manipulation request with the B2C access token to an second Azure Function.

Essentially, the first Azure Function serves as an interface for users to input their information and formulates the user's request, and the second Azure Function performs the request. The second Azure Function is assigned a managed identity ("Storage Blob Contributor") to perform the action requested by the B2C user on the Storage Account.

In the system itself, we want to assign Azure B2C users to specific containers. So we do not want other users accessing different containers. Is there a way to do this without sacrificing our current architecture in a secure way?

We currently have a solution, however it comes with its own issues. Each B2C user is assigned a container in the secondary Azure Function. There is a list of strings in the Azure Function that contain B2C object ids and containers, in the format of

```
const b2cUserToContainer = ['b2cUserObjectIdA:storageContainerA', 'b2cUserObjectIdB:storageContainerB'];
```

Whenever a request is sent to the secondary Azure Function, it decodes the B2C token and takes the user's B2C object id. Then the Azure Function checks the list of B2C object ids against the current user's decoded token. The B2C user is assigned the container that has the matching list value for object id. Although this works with a few users, this system will eventually have many more users - scalability is a major issue. Also, this list is the only way that users are checked as to what containers they can access. Is there another method of assigning B2C users to specific Azure Storage containers that is more secure?